# create var from local geojson file mapbox/leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, mapbox

I want to create a var `myGeojson` in an html file that uses the data in a separate locally stored .geojson or .js file. I can do this by creating a var in the .geojson file, which can be used in the html file. However I need to use multiple large unaltered geojson files, Is there a way to create the var in the html but store the data in the geojson?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>

        <script src='data/example.geojson'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-xxxxxxxx')
  .setView([37.8, -96], 4)
      .featureLayer.setGeoJSON(myGeojson);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

data/example.geojson

```
var myGeojson =
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the XHR functionality already included in `L.mapbox.featureLayer`?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <script>
            L.mapbox.accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-xxxxxxxx').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
            var layer1 = L.mapbox.featureLayer('data.geo.json').addTo(map);
            // You could add as much layers as you want
            // var layer2 = L.mapbox.featureLayer('moredata.geo.json').addTo(map);
            // Or you could load new data into an existing layer:
            //layer1.loadURL('newdata.geo.json');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

data.geo.json:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "Dinagat Islands"
    }
}
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jAkQ7v9XVIDCDnQQzpWK?p=preview

But as said in the comments, if you're really adament on taking an extra (in my eyes unnecessary) step then you can use a XHR library of choice and fetch the file and assign it to a variable (using jQuery's $.getJSON here):

```
// Empty featureLayer
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// Variable for your data
var geojsonData;

// Fetch the file
$.getJSON('data.geo.json', function (results) {
    // Assign the results to the geojsonData variable
    geojsonData = results;
    // Assign the data to the layer
    featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojsonData);
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ayYgF5fi1MKgTRBg3YAt?p=preview

But i don't see why you want to pull in another dependency like jQuery if featureLayer itself has the complete XHR functionality you need. But ok :)

Comment: thanks but tried .loadURL() doesn't seem to work. Work around is adding the var myGeojson =  to the start of the geojson file and then using L.geoJson(myGeojson); it works but still require me to edit the original geojson file which it what I want to avoid. Idealy I want to pull the text from the geojson file and and assign it as a var in the html.

Comment: `loadURL` _does_ work, here's an example using your own GeoJSON feature: http://plnkr.co/edit/jAkQ7v9XVIDCDnQQzpWK?p=preview

Comment: I've added the above example to my answer and included another solution which actually first loads the file and then assigns it to a variable. more cumbersome and uses another dependency but if that's what you want then you got it :)